# Text Pane color error

Tags: java, swing, fonts, colors, jtextpane

For some reason my text pane is white. It's a text pane (output) nested inside a j scrollpane.

```
        jScrollPane1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jScrollPane1.setBorder(null);
        jScrollPane1.setOpaque(false);

        output.setEditable(false);
        output.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        output.setBorder(null);
        output.setCaretColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        output.setDisabledTextColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        output.setHighlighter(null);
        output.setOpaque(false);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(output);
```

[image]

That's the only code affecting it. I don't know why this is happening, but I want the text pane to be black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, setting the background color of the `JTextPane` should be more than enough

[image: Back in back]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BlackTextPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BlackTextPane();
    }

    public BlackTextPane() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
                tp.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                tp.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(tp));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

How ever, you seem to making it transparent for some reason, `output.setOpaque(false);`.  Now you've made the `JScrollPane` transparent as well, which is good, but you forgot to make the view port transparent `jScrollPane1.getViewport().setOpaque(false);`

Scroll panes are made up three components, the `JScrollPane` itself, the `JViewport` which determines what gets displayed and you component (the view)

[ScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/doc-files/JScrollPane-1.gif)

Take a closer look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer, but just now I've come up with my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set the look and feel from "Nimbus" to "Windows" and make sure the Text Pane's "Opaque" is true.

Don't worry, these errors happen when you code at 1 in the morning.